# Script will only generate report for my Cases but not my If Else

Tags: shell, sh

To preface, I am an absolute noob so any help would be greatly appreciated. The issue with my script is that it is generating a .csv report for my cases accordingly except for my "semiannual" report. The semiannual is only supposed to be generated at the end of each month but I changed != to = just to make sure it is generating a report which it is not.

```
if [[ $(date -d "+1 day" +%m) = $(date +%m) ]]
then
    backNumDays="183"
    directory=$semianually
    _beginDate=$(date -d "180 days ago" +"%m%d%Y")
    report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"SemiAnnualReport".csv"
else
    :
fi

case $_day in
    Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)
        backNumDays="1"
        directory=$daily
        _beginDate=$(date -d "1 day ago" +"%m%d%Y")
        report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"DailyReport".csv"
        ;;
    Sun)
        backNumDays="7"
        directory=$weekly
        _beginDate=$(date -d "7 days ago" +"%m%d%Y")
        report="$_beginDate-$_endDate"WeeklyReport".csv"
        ;;
    *) ;;
esac
```

As stated, the reports are being generated for daily (and weekly as I just altered the case to include today's day [Tue]) but when trying to run for the semiannual report, nothing is being generated.

Comment: Well, you clearly don't have the full script, but if those lines are in this order, whatever happens in the IF condition, the values you set will be overwritten by the ones of the case clause.

Comment: Sorry, this was just the segment I was having issues with. I put my if/else below my cases and now it is working accordingly! 

One thing I noticed when testing the "semiannual" report is that it did not generate a daily report. Is this because only one of those conditions will be considered for the results? I reverted my if condition back to != to make sure the report is only generated on the last day of the month and my daily report is generating again.

Comment: A script is executed sequentially, so the variable you are using to generate the reports will have the last set of values. We're always one of the day of the week, so your case clause will always set the variable to some values. So if you place the "if" before, whatever the day, the case clause will have the final word. On the other hand, the "if" after the "case" will modify the variable only if it's month end (and will not generate a daily report for that day).

Comment: Ok! I'll use separate variables to ensure all reports are generated for given days. Thank you!